# How to handle and process data from a form?

Tags: php, html

This is my code (index-wamp.php):

```
`<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Index of Commons || Sandwich Fun&reg;</title>
      
<!-- SANDWICH FUN (C) COURTESY OF MISTY CO, WITH PARTNERS
2023-02-04 20:48
--Revision--
--Revision--        -->
    
<!-- Det är psykologi. Frågan är bara hur psykologi riktigt tänker. Det verkar väldigt konstigt. -->
    
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    
<link rel="stylesheet" href="smorgass.css">
<meta charset="UTF-8"> <!-- This is a game! -->
<meta name="author" content="Elise Knuuti of Misty Co">
    
<meta name="keywords" content="horses, game, horse-sim">
<meta name="description" content="A fully-featured horse game (sim) for ALL ages!">
      
<!-- It is forbidden to talk about Granberg in the company. -->
     
<!-- & Linda Jonasson & -->
     
<!-- The voices talk so creepy. They have destroyed my whole life. -->
     
<!-- Kommer att skicka ett hatbrev till Granberg -->
     
<!-- I'm going to code my game. I saw a picture of Magdalena Andersson. They are really creepy in Sweden. Ulf Kristersson is a perfect prime minister. -->
     
<!-- I have to explain my code. I have a few bugs. They are difficult. Josefine's mamma is banned. I have this one bug, problem with it. I don't understand the bug, it was text in the PHP book. :) Hm... What kind of bug can that be? Really, it's because it's a dangerous game! :D Now I get it! -->
     
</head>
<body>
    
<form action='register.php' method='POST'>
<fieldset>
<label for="username">Användarnamn:</label>
<input type='text' name='username'><br>
<label for="email">E-post:</label>
<input type='text' name='email'><br>

<label for="password">Lösenord:</label><input type="password" name="password"><br>
<input type='submit' value='LOGGA IN()!'>
</fieldset>

<?php

$a = $a + rand(1,10);

$b = $b + rand(1,10);

$answer = $a + $b;

?>

<?php echo "$a + $b ="; ?>
<input type='text' name='hausin'>
<input type='submit' name='captcha_reloaded' value='Sign in with CAPTCHA'>";

<!-- <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<note>
<to>Computer HQ</to>
<from>Elise Knuuti</from>
<heading>Reminder</heading>
<body>We have high security in the company. I just finished a CAPTCHA (it's working!), and I need to fix the bugs. This is a painting computer. You should recall I want to create a phone.</body>
</note> -->
    
</body>
</html>`
```

Now, I want to check if the user put in the right result of the addition! Do I do this on the page register.php? Or, do I do this in the same file (index-wamp.php)? And so on.

I want to know how to process form data.

Comment: `Now, I want to check if the user put in the right result of the addition!` - is this like a `captcha`? If it is then you need to store the value of the calculation in a session variable before you can determine if the user input is correct

Comment: `$a = $a + rand(1,10);` and `$b = $b + rand(1,10);` - where are $a & $b defined before using here?

Comment: It's just the implicit declaration

Comment: How do I proceed the form to the correct page if I have this if statement (and the action_page is in the form variable, e.g. action="register.php"): `if (isset($_POST['captcha_reloaded'])) {
   
   if ($_POST['hausin'] === $answer) {
    
    
    
   }
      }`

Comment: Why not try it out and see what happens?

Answer (score -1):

I think I solved it.

`<form action='<?php if ($answer === $hausin) { echo "register.php"; } ?>' method='POST'>`

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it. Why do you want to change the form action? Anything not working when you use `register.php`  all the time?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).